# Can't install amdgpu drivers for Radeon graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu

I'm encountering errors while trying to install `amdgpu` drivers for my Radeon R2 / R3 graphics card using `./amdgpu-install -y` command as recommended on [this page.](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html) Can anyone explain what the problem is here please?

ps, I've added output from `sudo lshw -C video` below as well.

```
    freeworlder@freeworlder-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~/Desktop/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04$ ./amdgpu-install -y
[sudo] password for freeworlder: 
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                  
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg         
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages [106 kB]   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:7 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:9 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '20.20-1098277' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pin'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libffi7:i386 libllvm10 libllvm11:i386 libomxil-bellagio-bin
  libomxil-bellagio0 libreoffice-style-tango libstdc++6:i386 libudev1:i386
  libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-pin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,684 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pin 20.20-1098277 [2,684 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pin.
(Reading database ... 447715 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pin_20.20-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm10 libreoffice-style-tango
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-core amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-lib gst-omx-amdgpu
  libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu-common
  libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 libdrm2-amdgpu
  libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 libgbm1-amdgpu
  libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa
  libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libgles1-amdgpu-mesa libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libllvm10.0-amdgpu
  libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 libosmesa6-amdgpu libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386
  libxatracker2-amdgpu libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
Suggested packages:
  libglide3 libglide3:i386
Recommended packages:
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 | libtxc-dxtn0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu amdgpu-core amdgpu-dkms amdgpu-dkms-firmware amdgpu-lib amdgpu-lib32
  gst-omx-amdgpu libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-amdgpu-common libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386
  libdrm2-amdgpu libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers
  libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 libgbm1-amdgpu libgbm1-amdgpu:i386
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386
  libgles1-amdgpu-mesa libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libgles2-amdgpu-mesa
  libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 libllvm10.0-amdgpu libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386
  libosmesa6-amdgpu libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 libxatracker2-amdgpu
  libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu
0 upgraded, 42 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/79.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 751 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms-firmware 1:5.6.0.15-1098277 [4,437 kB]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms 1:5.6.0.15-1098277 [5,493 kB]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-core 20.20-1098277 [2,216 B]
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.100-1098277 [38.0 kB]
Get:5 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-common 1.0.0-1098277 [4,620 B]
Get:6 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 1:2.4.100-1098277 [23.7 kB]
Get:7 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 1:2.4.100-1098277 [23.8 kB]
Get:8 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm10.0-amdgpu 1:10.0-1098277 [17.3 MB]
Get:9 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [2,054 kB]
Get:10 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libglapi-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [24.8 kB]
Get:11 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:20.0.5-1098277 [7,129 kB]
Get:12 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.100-1098277 [35.6 kB]
Get:13 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 1:2.4.100-1098277 [21.1 kB]
Get:14 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1 1:2.4.100-1098277 [22.3 kB]
Get:15 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libllvm10.0-amdgpu 1:10.0-1098277 [15.2 MB]
Get:16 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [2,187 kB]
Get:17 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libglapi-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [25.2 kB]
Get:18 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri 1:20.0.5-1098277 [7,263 kB]
Get:19 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libxatracker2-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [1,417 kB]
Get:20 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgbm1-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [26.5 kB]
Get:21 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [102 kB]
Get:22 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [4,344 B]
Get:23 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [8,288 B]
Get:24 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles2-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [12.0 kB]
Get:25 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx 1:20.0.5-1098277 [141 kB]
Get:26 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libosmesa6-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [3,609 kB]
Get:27 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [2,611 kB]
Get:28 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [2,201 kB]
Get:29 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu 1:19.1.0-1098277 [58.1 kB]
Get:30 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ gst-omx-amdgpu 1.0.0.1-1098277 [58.5 kB]
Get:31 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-lib 20.20-1098277 [2,140 B]
Get:32 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu 20.20-1098277 [1,688 B]
Get:33 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libxatracker2-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [1,212 kB]
Get:34 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgbm1-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [28.0 kB]
Get:35 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [109 kB]
Get:36 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [4,344 B]
Get:37 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles1-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [8,292 B]
Get:38 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgles2-amdgpu-mesa 1:20.0.5-1098277 [11.9 kB]
Get:39 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx 1:20.0.5-1098277 [150 kB]
Get:40 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libosmesa6-amdgpu 1:20.0.5-1098277 [3,414 kB]
Get:41 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers 1:20.0.5-1098277 [2,515 kB]
Get:42 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-lib32 20.20-1098277 [1,832 B]
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms-firmware.
(Reading database ... 447728 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.6.0.15-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms.
(Reading database ... 448106 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-amdgpu-dkms_5.6.0.15-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-core.
Preparing to unpack .../1-amdgpu-core_20.20-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-core (20.20-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-common.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../8-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-core (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1098277) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64.
(Reading database ... 450064 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1098277) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1098277) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386.
(Reading database ... 450100 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb 
...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ..
.
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../11-xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu_19.1.0-1098277_amd64
.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gst-omx-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../12-gst-omx-amdgpu_1.0.0.1-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib.
Preparing to unpack .../13-amdgpu-lib_20.20-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib (20.20-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../14-amdgpu_20.20-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu (20.20-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb .
..
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../23-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.0.5-1098277_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib32.
Preparing to unpack .../24-amdgpu-lib32_20.20-1098277_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib32 (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1098277) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-62-lowlatency
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-62-lowlatency
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms-fir
mware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-62-lowlatency (x86_64
)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more informatio
n.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1098277) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Setting up mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-109
8277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.0.5-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.20-1098277) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
freeworlder@freeworlder-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~/Desktop/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04$
```

Graphics card information:

```
freeworlder@freeworlder-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for freeworlder: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: e2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0d00000-f0d3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
freeworlder@freeworlder-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15AST:~$
```